# Trying to acess an Open OffShore Account for Someone

Tags: scams

A person that has left the states to work says he can't get into his account from current work area, Dubai.  He has sent me Access code, username, password and pin to see if I can access it from US.  Is this a scam?  He just wants me to see if I can get in?

Comment: Is the person who left the States someone you've known since childhood, or some random stranger off the Internet?

Answer (score 9):

Yes it is a scam. It can progress in different directions. Stay away.